# google maps resize not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following code for my google maps object:

```
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': googleAddress}, function (results, status){ 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
            var mapOptions = { zoom: 16, center:results[0].geometry.location, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
            map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions); 
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: results[0].geometry.location,
                   map: map,
                   title: googleAddress
                 });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            });
        }
    })
```

This element starts inside a "Display:none" div, so when I fire the click event to open the div, I also fire a window event 'resize' (to load the entire map... you can read about those issues elsewhere on why you have to fire resize):

```
showMap = function(){
        if ($('#map').hasClass('hide')){
            $('#map').removeClass('hide');
            $window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        }
        else{
            $('#map').addClass('hide');
        }
    };
```

This works as far as displaying the map in the full div, the problem is my center is wrong.  I have a marker located at the address passed in (Verified the marker is at the right location), but the marker is off the screen (just off the top left corner).  If you zoom out 1 click, the marker is just inside the top left corner.

I have also tried(with no luck)

```
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                    var center = map.getCenter();
                    map.setCenter(center);
                });
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you centered the map on the geocoded result, it had zero size, that put the center in the upper left corner.  When you run this function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
   var center = map.getCenter();
   map.setCenter(center);
});
```

You aren't changing the center.  If you want the geocoded result in the center, keep a reference to it (or the marker) and put that position at the center after triggering the map resize event.